# Trouble give the option to add more than one entry into Binary Tree? Right now code only allows for one

Tags: java, binary-tree

In the code below. I a trying to allow the user to enter entries into the program. Right now they can only add one entry into the program. How can I edit it so the user can have the option to enter another entry into the program.

Example of output:
Enter ID: 444
Enter FName: John
Enter Lname: Thompson

Would you like to enter another entry Y/N?Y
Enter ID:1
Enter FName: Gail
Enter Lname: Jennings

Would you like to enter another entry Y/N?N

If yes is clicked I want to add the gathered data into the binary tree and allow the user to enter another id. How can I do that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class clubmember {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int id;
         String fname, lname;
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Enter ID>");
         id = input.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Enter first name >");
         fname = input.next();

         System.out.println("Enter last name >");
         lname = input.next();



         BinaryTreeTest foo = new BinaryTreeTest(); 


           Person per1 = new Person(id, fname, lname);
           BinaryTreeTest.Node nod1 = new BinaryTreeTest.Node(per1);

           Person per2 = new Person(734, "Smith", "Rick");
           Person per3 = new Person(324, "Gates", "Jill");

           foo.insert(nod1, per2);
           foo.insert(nod1, per3);

           foo.printInOrder(nod1);


    }
}



public class BinaryTreeTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    new BinaryTreeTest().run();
  }

  // Node Class
  static class Node {
    Node left;

    Node right;

    Person value;

    public Node(Person value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  public void run() {

  }

  public void insert(Node node, Person value) {
    if (value.getId() < node.value.getId()) {
      if (node.left != null) {
        insert(node.left, value);
      } else {
        System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to left of "
            + node.value);
        node.left = new Node(value);
      }
    } else if (value.getId() > node.value.getId()) {
      if (node.right != null) {
        insert(node.right, value);
      } else {
        System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to right of "
            + node.value);
        node.right = new Node(value);
      }
    }
  }

  public void printInOrder(Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
      printInOrder(node.left);
      System.out.println("  Traversed " + node.value);
      printInOrder(node.right);
    }
  }
}


public class Person {
    private final int id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;


    public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(id) + ": " + firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `do { ... } while ()` loop.  Something like

```
boolean more;
do {
  insertOneUser();
  System.out.println("Add another?");
  more = "y".equals(input.next().toLowerCase());
} while (more);
```

Comment: nah I need to enter a user and the id. Enter ID> x | Enter Name> y | Enter Last Name > z

Answer (score 0):

you require to use a collection class to store the objects created..
I;d suggest you use a TreeSet to store the values.. (you need to modify the isert method to add the node to the TreeSet.

This should give you the desired result.